# SQL Select COUNT for Multiple Columns in a Single Query

Tags: sql, select, count

I am relatively new to SQL and have only a working knowledge of the language, but I've been tasked with creating a table that provides a summary of a set of data I'm working with in another table. Specifically, I am working with a table that looks like this (apologies for formatting of table as I couldn't get it to display properly vertically):

Table 1

Col1: a, b, c, d, a, d, b

Col2: dog, cat, dog, cat, horse, bird, cat

And, I want to use `SELECT COUNT` to output the number of unique occurrences of "a" in one column and then the number of unique occurrences of "dog" in a second column (they are not dependent on each other in the environment we're working in). The new summary table would look like this:

Col1 (# of "a"): 2

Col2 ("# of dogs"): 2

My select statements look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (Col1) as '# of a' FROM "Table 1" WHERE Col1 = 'a'
```

And this for the second column:

```
SELECT COUNT (Col2) as '# of dogs' FROM "Table 1" WHERE Col2 = 'dog'
```

How can I combine the two `SELECT COUNT` queries to get the desired table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this if your sql platform supports the CASE statement.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '# of a'
    ,  SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'dog' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '# of dogs'
FROM "Table 1"
```

The above query uses `SUM` instead of `COUNT` and the inner expression returns 0 or 1 depending on if the condition evaluates to false or true.

Comment: Actually this should work in some form on most DBs. Even if does not support CASE should support some conditional data like IFF...

Comment: Thanks, all for the answers! Our cloud-based reporting tool supports the CASE statement and so this worked swimmingly. Appreciate the helpful insights and your time!

Comment: @wyattburp86 - glad to help and glad it worked. *(If this had not worked and also for next time)* to get answers better suited for your problem and DBMS we advise you to tag the appropriate DBMS in your question. I/you got lucky that the case statement was supported in your DBMS with my answer but it might not have been so.

Answer (score 1):

Could just combine the two select as items in another select. Not elegant, but easy to implement.

```
Select
  cntA     = (SELECT COUNT (Col1) as '# of a' FROM "Table 1" WHERE Col1 = 'a' )
, cntDog   = (SELECT COUNT (Col2) as '# of dogs' FROM "Table 1" WHERE Col2 = 'dog')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control at all over the requirements, change them. SQL isn't designed to turn rows into columns in the way you'd need to do here. You *can* do it. You just probably *shouldn't*.

The best option is to just run two different queries. Those will both be optimized and run quickly, and then in your software you can figure out what to do with those two results.

Next best option:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(col1='a',1,0)) AS a, SUM(IF(col2='dog',1,0)) AS dog
```

(Your question doesn't tag a specific database engine, so I went with a MySQL-specific solution here mainly because it seems easiest to read as pseudocode. If you're using a different RDBMS, the code will look different, but will follow the same basic pattern.)